# What's the right way to use Wildfly 10 with Hibernate and MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, maven, wildfly-10

I'm new to this, did a lot of research now and still I'm not able to develop a working Wildfly / Hibernate / MongoDB Environment. 
Here is basically did so far:

- [Read this Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.1#ogm-configuration-jbossmodule)
- Download Wildfly 10
- Download Hibernate OGM 5.1.0.Final and ORM 5.1.4 Modules Archive
- Extract Modules into wildfly/modules
- Download/Install MongoDB (i tried 2 Versions)

  - via Brew on Mac
  - via Ubuntu in an VM
- Create new Maven Web Project in Netbeans

Next Step is to edit pom.xml, jboss-deployment-structure.xml, persistence.xml. And that's the Point where the trouble begins.  I tried different entries and get different errors. Right now my configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.hibernate.ogm" slot="5.1" services="export" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb" slot="5.1" services="export" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I saw different Versions of this file, sometimes with slot="main", sometimes with services="import".

Persitence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="comic-PU" transaction-type="JTA">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
 <properties>
   <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.1"/>
   <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb"/>
   <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="comicDB"/>
   <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost"/>
   <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port" value="27017"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
</properties>
```

I'am pretty sure here is something wrong. When deploying the Project, Wildfly tries to read persistence.xml, then stuck for a moment and:

```
20:58:33,255 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for comic-PU
21:03:32,767 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "MYAPP.war")]'
21:03:32,772 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "ComicFeeder-1.0.war" was rolled back with no failure message
```

Pom.xml is mostly auto-generated, i added

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>

 <archive>
   <manifestEntries>
      <mode>development</mode>
      <url>${project.url}</url>
      <Dependencies>org.hibernate.ogm:5.1 services, org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.1 services</Dependencies>
   </manifestEntries>
  </archive>
```

Is the manifest entry necessary?

An Errors I got:

- Wildfly: org.hibernate.search.engine 5.6.1.Final not found

  - in wildfly/modules/org/hibernate/search/engine the modules name is "5.6.1.Final-orm51" -> renamed it to 5.6.1.Final, edit the Entry in 5.6.1.Final/modules.xml
  - Wildfly then starts without that error
  - This looks like a bug to me

Where is my mistake? What's your "workflow" when you start a new project with hibernate, wildfly and mongodb? 
Would it be easier to use Glassfish or any other Server?
Some Tutorials I found are outdated or just did not work (for me).

Comment: Try marking those dependencies as `<scope>provided</scope>` since you're adding them as modules. I'm not sure why there isn't a better error message.

Comment: The `module.xml` files for the modules you added would be helpful too.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I added the scope tag, but nothing changed. Do you mean the OGM and ORM related modules.xml Files? They are available from: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/ogm/hibernate-ogm-modules/5.1.0.Final/hibernate-ogm-modules-5.1.0.Final-wildfly-10-dist.zip AND https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-orm-modules/5.1.4.Final/hibernate-orm-modules-5.1.4.Final-wildfly-10-dist.zip

Comment: To get a clean deployment I shut down wildfly, deleted the content in standalone/deployment, did a clean build and deployed the war. Wildfly give me this error:  "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"ComicFeeder.war\".PARSE"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
            "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
        ]

Comment: I assume you put those modules in the `$JBOSS_HOME/modules` directory right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: There should be some messages above the `WFLYCTL0288` message. Those likely give a better idea of what the issue may be.